# What does it mean for a family to be "maximal with respect to"... certain condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading this book by Blackadar: "Operator algebras, theory of $C^*$-algebra and von Neumann algebras" (link: http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/bruceb/Cycr.pdf), and I ran into this term: "families that are maximal with respect to..." certain condition, that I couldn't quite figure out, here's a couple of examples where it is used:

On page 246:

> ... if $\{ p_i \}$ is a family of abelian projections which is maximal
>   with respect to the condition that the central carriers $z_{p_i}$ are
>   pairwise orthogonal...

And on page 273:

> ... let $\{ \phi_i: i \in \Omega \}$ be a family of normal linear
>   functionals which is maximal with respect to the condition that the
>   supports $p_i$ are mutually orthogonal...

- I was kind of confused, in general, What do they mean when some family is "**maximal with respect to...**"?

:)

Comment: in plain English - it means you can't add anything else to the family without spoiling your property

Answer (score 0):

It means the following:

> Let $(S,<)$ be an ordered set. An element $s_m\in S$ is **maximal** if
>   $\nexists s\in S:s_m<s$.

Both your cases, the ordering is given by inclusion of sets.

Comment: But, in the first example, what is $S$? Is a member of $S$ a family of abelian projections $B = \{ g_i \}$ whose central carriers $z_{g_i}$ are pairwise orthogonal? If that's the case, what does $<$ mean in this context? How do you order these families of projections? Thanks so much for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: @LuisAlmaguer Yes, in the first example $S$ is the set of families of abelian projections etc., and the ordering is given by inclusion, i.e. $B<B'\Leftrightarrow B\subset B'$.

Comment: Thank you, just to be perfectly clear, projections on a von Neumann algebra $M$ are ordered by inclusion right? $B \leq B'$ means that every member of the family $B$ is included in $B'$? That is, the condition $p \leq g$ is satisfied by all members $p \in B$ and $g \in B'$? I was going in another direction.

Comment: @LuisAlmaguer No, I think it should be just $\forall p\in B: p\in B'$.